# Simple Calculator using python3

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming

I'm trying to make a simple calculator with only this types of code. It keep on giving me continues operations even though the operation should be provided/chosen by user. What should I do? :(

```
def calc():
    if mode == "1":
        print("Addition")
        main = add()
    elif mode == "2":
        print("Subtraction")
        main = sub()
    elif mode == "3":
        print("Multiplication")
        main = mult()
    elif mode == "4":
        print("Division")
        main = div()
        print("Quotient is equal to", main)
    elif mode == "5":
        print("Modulo")
        main = mod()
    elif mode == "6":
        print("Raise a number to an exponent")
        main = exp()
    elif mode == "7":
        print("Square root")
        main = sq()


def add():
    x = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    y = float(input("Enter second number: "))
    mad = x+y
    print("Sum is equal to", mad)
    return
def sub():
    x = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    y = float(input("Enter second number: "))
    mad = x-y
    print("Difference is equal to", mad)
    return
def mult():
    x = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    y = float(input("Enter second number: "))
    mad = x*y
    print("Product is equal to", mad)
    return
def div():
    x = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    y = float(input("Enter second number: "))
    mad = x/y
    print("Quotient is equal to", mad)
    return
def mod():
    x = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    y = float(input("Enter second number: "))
    mad = x%y
    print("Remainder is equal to", mad)
    return
def exp():
    x = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    y = float(input("Enter second number: "))
    mad = x**y
    print(x, "raised to", y, "is equal to", main)
    return
def sq():
    x = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    mad = x**0.5
    print("Square root of", x, "is", mad)
    return

print("1. Add")
print("2. Subtract")
print("3. Multiply")
print("4. Division")
print("5. Modulo")
print("6. Exponent")
print("7. Square root")
print("8. Exit")
mode = input("What do you want to do? ")

calc()
add()
sub()
mult()
div()
mod()
exp()
sq()
```

It keeps asking me for input numbers then continuously provides answers for all operations one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have called every function after you've called cal(). You should comment the other lines. Besides, you have called main on exp instead of mad. I guess you wanted to do the following:

```
def calc():
    if mode == "1":
        print("Addition")
        main = add()
    elif mode == "2":
        print("Subtraction")
        main = sub()
    elif mode == "3":
        print("Multiplication")
        main = mult()
    elif mode == "4":
        print("Division")
        main = div()
        print("Quotient is equal to", main)
    elif mode == "5":
        print("Modulo")
        main = mod()
    elif mode == "6":
        print("Raise a number to an exponent")
        main = exp()
    elif mode == "7":
        print("Square root")
        main = sq()


def add():
    x = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    y = float(input("Enter second number: "))
    mad = x+y
    print("Sum is equal to", mad)
    return
def sub():
    x = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    y = float(input("Enter second number: "))
    mad = x-y
    print("Difference is equal to", mad)
    return
def mult():
    x = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    y = float(input("Enter second number: "))
    mad = x*y
    print("Product is equal to", mad)
    return
def div():
    x = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    y = float(input("Enter second number: "))
    mad = x/y
    print("Quotient is equal to", mad)
    return
def mod():
    x = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    y = float(input("Enter second number: "))
    mad = x%y
    print("Remainder is equal to", mad)
    return
def exp():
    x = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    y = float(input("Enter second number: "))
    mad = x**y
    print(x, "raised to", y, "is equal to", mad)
    return
def sq():
    x = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    mad = x**0.5
    print("Square root of", x, "is", mad)
    return

mode = input("What do you want to do? ")
calc()

"""print("1. Add")
print("2. Subtract")
print("3. Multiply")
print("4. Division")
print("5. Modulo")
print("6. Exponent")
print("7. Square root")
print("8. Exit")



add()
sub()
mult()
div()
mod()
exp()
sq()"""
```

Comment: I'm not sure you really want float cast the x and y variables when calculating "Modulo". I think you should accept only int types